# Groovy static methods with dots

Tags: groovy

Why do I have a compilation error for this code:

```
class SomeList {

    final String field

    SomeList(String field) {
        this.field = field
    }

    static SomeList "Regular name of method"() {
        return new SomeList("Regular name of method")
    }

    static SomeList "Name with.dot"() {
        return new SomeList("Name with.dot")
    }
}

class SomeListTests {

    @Test
    def "some list test"() {
        //given
        SomeList list = SomeList()

        //when
        list."Regular name of method"()

        //then
        //compilation error
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Error:Groovyc: While compiling tests of example-project_test: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/home/alex/Projects/example-project/src/test/groovy/SomeListTests.groovy' Problem loading class SomeList

I did not find any restrictions in the documentation for method names as String.

When i create main method with GroovyShell and try to start script with this method it compiles.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
        shell.run(new File("path/to/Script.groovy"), Collections.emptyList())
        println "Everything is cool"
    }
}
```

And this is Script.groovy:

```
SomeList."Regular name of method"()
SomeList."Name with.dot"()
```

Comment: Dot (.) opreator can not be used in the method name

Comment: but when i use GroovyShell it runs

Comment: What version of groovy? `BUG` errors are usually bugs that should be reported

Comment: 2.4.15 in `build.gradle`. Executing `./gradlew test` leads to `Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> Illegal method name "Name with.dot" in class SomeList
`

Comment: Created a bug in groovy jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8724

Answer (score 0):

I create `Test.groovy` file as `Groovy Script` file in IDEA:

```
import org.junit.Test

class SomeList {

    final String field

    SomeList(String field) {
        this.field = field
    }

    static SomeList "Regular name of method"() {
        return new SomeList("Regular name of method")
    }

    static SomeList "Name with.dot"() {
        return new SomeList("Name with.dot")
    }
}

class SomeListTests {

    @Test
    void "some list test"() {
        //given
        SomeList list = new SomeList()

        //when
        println list."Regular name of method"()

        //then
        println list."Name with.dot"()
    }
}
```

And it works fine for me. I'm using Groovy 2.4.15.
The output is:

```
SomeList@cb51256
SomeList@59906517
```

Comment: It's really strange... i have 2.4.15 in build.gradle and on my machine but even if i try to start test in IDEA or to execute `./gradlew test` i have compilation error

Comment: What is your OS and java version? I could try to reproduce this issue on another environment. And you sure, what in your code exists `SomeList list =` **new** `SomeList()`

Comment: Linux 16.04 and Java 1.8.0_171. Yes i've added `new` but nothing changed. Even if i add only import of `SomeList` and don't use it i have compilation error.

Comment: You using Spock for test? If so, what version?

Comment: Yes i use spock v1.1. But in this example code i didn't use it. Its pure JUnit v4.12